# Iteration with if condition not working in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I wrote the following script

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import glob

path = raw_input('In which dir do you want to look for the files?')   
path += '/*.txt'
files=glob.glob(path)   
for seq in files:     
    f=open(seq)  
    total = 0
    for line in f:
        if 'NAR' in line:
                print("bum")
f.close()
```

So if I have a file like this:

```
NAR 56 rob
NAR 0-0 co
FOR 56 gs
FRI 69 ds
NIR 87 sdh
```

I would expect my code to print

```
bum bum
```

Then I tried the following after reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004636/nested-for-loop-in-python-not-working)

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import glob

path = raw_input('In which dir do you want to look for the files?')   
files=glob.glob(path)   
for seq in files:     
    with open(seq) as input_file:  
            for line in input_file:
                if 'NAR' in line:
                        print("bum")
input_file.close()
```

but both do not work. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you passing the FULL directory path to the glob() method ? and also print the files returned by that function for debugging purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list of `files` just contains the directory, and will not look for files as written. If you are trying to match, for example, `txt` files you would need to say

```
path += '\*.txt'
```

So `glob` looks for `txt` files. Instead of

```
'C:\folder\folder'
```

The search would then be

```
'C:\folder\folder\*.txt'
```

Comment: Good point. I followed your suggestion and also @Anmol_uppal 's one. It still does not print anything, but if I include `print(files)` in the script I get `[]`. It seems that it does not find any file, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If `path` is indeed a path of an existing directory, without wildcards, then `glob.glob` will return a single-item list with just that directory.

You may want, before the `glob.glob` call, to add something like

```
if not path.endswith('*'):
    path = os.path.join(path, '*')
```

or more generally, your condition could be:

```
if '*' not in path:
```

though if you're happy with a wildcard anywhere it's not obvious where you would add it if it was missing.